# Deserialize Facebook Workplace SCIM Rest API response

Tags: c#, json, facebook, api

I'm trying to deserialize the below response to a strongly typed object using C# NewtonSoft.Json library. **The issue is how to deserialize the last part**

`"urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0": {"department": "Headquarters"}`
into an object.

```
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0",
    "urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0"
  ],
  "userName": "ihabs@olympic.qa",
  "name": {
    "formatted": "Ihab Mahmoud"
  },
  "active": true,
  "emails": [
    {
      "primary": true,
      "type": "work",
      "value": "ihabs@olympic.qa"
    }
  ],
  "addresses": [
    {
      "type": "work",
      "formatted": "QOC Headquarter",
      "primary": true
    }
  ],
  "urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0": {
    "department": "Headquarters"
  }
}
```

**My Strongle Type Classes are**

```
public class WPClass
    {
        public List<string> Schemas { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public NameNode Name { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public List<EmailNode> Emails { get; set; }
        public List<AddressNode> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
```

**The class for Address node**

```
public class AddressNode
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string formatted { get; set; }
    public bool Primary { get; set; }

}
```

**the class for Email Node**

```
public class EmailNode
{
    public bool Primary { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

**the class for Name node**

```
public class NameNode
{
    public string formatted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your strongly typed class?

Comment: Please check my reviewed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should only create a property, and use a `JsonProperty` attribute :

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0")]
public YourEnterpriseType Enterprise { get; set; }
```

Not sure on the `Enterprise` name though.

The [documentation about that](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm).

Comment: And a shorthand is `[JsonProperty("urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0")]`